# Extending / Mocking enums

Tags: java, enums, junit4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mocking Java enum to add a value to test fail case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323505/mocking-java-enum-to-add-a-value-to-test-fail-case)

I have a switch statement that works on an enum. The "default" case of the switch is to throw a runtime exception. It's coded like this to trap the situation where someone adds a value to the enum but forgets to update the switch statement.

I want to test this execution path, but I am struggling to find a way of doing so without putting an unused enum value into my live code. Is this a misuse of enum, or is there an accepted way of writing this test?

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323505/mocking-java-enum-to-add-a-value-to-test-fail-case

Comment: Are you inclined to use any mocking frameworks like Mockito?

Comment: Mokito can't do it afaik - but it looks like PowerMock might be the answer - I'll look in to it. Thanks

Comment: PowerMock works like a charm - thanks very much for the suggestion.

Comment: That is not in the answer so Vote up.

Answer (score 1):

What I am thinking you could do to test this is have a test case where you basically get all values of your enum like

```
T[] allEnumValues = enumValue.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

or

```
T[] allEnumValues = enumType.values();
```

and then take each one and put it in the `switch` statement. If you get an exception you have a problem.

PS: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) to the `getEnumConstants()` method.

Comment: This isn't quite what I want but is an interesting approach. I actually WANT to pass in an enum value that does not exist in the switch statement so that I can prove that the RTE is thrown. ( My client is very keen on code coverage ..... )