# How do I assert an IOException message with JUnit Test annotation?

Tags: java, junit

When I use [@Rule](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Rule.html) with [ExpectedException](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) as shown below in 1st ([adapted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469911/how-do-i-assert-my-exception-message-with-junit-test-annotation)), I get the error "Unhandled Exception type" in the Class2testTest class at (*).

```
package class2test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Class2test {
    public Class2test() throws IOException{
        throw new IOException("j");
    }
}

package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

import class2test.Class2test;

public class Class2testTest {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        expectedEx.expect(IOException.class);
        expectedEx.expectMessage("j");
        new Class2test(); //(*)
    }

}
```

I do not understand this: [adapted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469911/how-do-i-assert-my-exception-message-with-junit-test-annotation) is reproducible (with a RuntimeException rather an IOException it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the thrown exception in the method's signature:

```
public void test() throws Exception {
```